# How to implement fftshift in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, fft

The fftshift can be used to change between index conventions in fft. Basically, every implementation of a fft comes with it, e.g. [numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fftshift.html) but there is none in TensorFlow.

How should fftshift (and its inverse, ifftshift) be implemented in TensorFlow in a differentiable manner?

Comment: There is an fftshift in tensorflow now. But, it doesnt operate on batches in a straightforward manner.